# Application that can get Location and runs on android 4.0.3+

Tags: android, android-studio, location

For android versions less than 6 just adding these permission requests to the manifest works:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

But for android version 6 I need explicitly request permission too to get the location:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1340);
```

The problem is that If I add the above code the App works only on android 6 and fails to run on lower versions as `requestPermissions` does not exist on lower versions. and If I remove it I won't be able to get the location on android 6.

What can I do that my app be able to get the location on android 4.0.3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the API level of the phone that is running your app like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     //later than 4.x - so here you can run the code
     //ideally you want to make this call in a helper method which you then annotate with the @TargetApi
     requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1340);
    }
else{
  //nothing to do in your case ?
}
```

You can also use `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` in the methods where you want to make "Lollipop+" calls.